# Как одним запросом сделать две выборки из одной таблицы?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с событиями.
Нужно выбрать из нее 20 прошедших событий и все будущие. Можно ли это сделать одним запросом?

Comment: @oleg_ismaylov ну, если использовать UNION можно и одним запросом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать UNION [link text](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/UNION.html)